# What is the difference between booting into Ubuntu normally and in recovery mode?

Tags: boot, grub2, kernel

I have seen that the grub menu entry for recovery on my Ubuntu is :

```
linux   /boot/vmlinuz-3.16.0-45-generic root=UUID=c1f08a7e-c1e0-4409-97cb-8094359408cb ro recovery nomodeset
```

but I didn't find any explanation to what does the recovery flag involve. Is that a way to configure the kernel in a different way? Is that only true for Ubuntu?

Since I have only one kernel on my computer I guess it boots in the same kernel only with different modules loaded and different options set.

Answer (score 3):

Recovery is for every kernel. If you have 5 kernels, you'll have 5 recoveries and they'll be named after the names of the kernels in grub. You have other options than booting the normal system when booting into recovery (for example freeing space or updating software or opening a root shell). If you boot the normal system from recovery, that's not a full graphical boot which means that not all graphic drivers can be loaded this way. That's why you might get worse graphics performance. Also, boot flags are set differently.

What does `nomodeset` mean specifically? I'll just copy this one from [here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1613132):

> The newest kernels have moved the video mode setting into the kernel.
>   So all the programming of the hardware specific clock rates and
>   registers on the video card happen in the kernel rather than in the X
>   driver when the X server starts.. This makes it possible to have high
>   resolution nice looking splash (boot) screens and flicker free
>   transitions from boot splash to login screen. Unfortunately, on some
>   cards this doesnt work properly and you end up with a black screen.
>   Adding the nomodeset parameter instructs the kernel to not load video
>   drivers and use BIOS modes instead until X is loaded.

Answer (score 0):

*Recovery mode* is a boot method that allows you to perform certain administrative tasks and recover your faulty Ubuntu system. This mode is useful when no session is able to be opened because your hard drives are failing, when the file systems are corrupt or it is impossible to start Ubuntu because a graphical session can not be started (e.g an update of the graphical server no longer supports your old proprietary drivers) or when the password of the primary user account is forgotten. Once you have selected the recovery mode, the root partition is mounted read-only that avoids writing information to your hard disk.

It is not only applicable to Ubuntu but to other Linux flavors as well.

In the systems using (or used to use) Upstart, when you boot into recovery mode, the init daemon run the scripts in `/etc/init/rcS.conf`. In addition, if you do not want to see the 'recovery' entrieds in grub menu, you can set the `GRUB_DISABLE_RECOVERY=true` in `/etc/default/grub`

Comment: What does the **recovery** flag trigger when opening a root shell? What are the specific differences in terms of kernel config when booting into recovery?

Comment: Id like to know this too, I have a system that works fine in recovery and not without it 18.10